# Facebook staticFBML detect fan

Tags: facebook, fbml, facebook-page, staticfbml

How do I detect if a visitor to my staticFBML page is a fan or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to detect a fan here http://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2010/tracking-user-engagement-on-facebook-fan-pages/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tag fb:visible-to-connection http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:visible-to-connection.

This tag will allow you to display content on the page to only people that are fans.

Good luck!